# How to edit associations as a single entity

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I have a web app where I have **posts**, and each post has and belongs to many **tags**. I want the tags associated with each post to be editable using a single text field, as a comma separated list. This allows tags to be added, removed and edited(a removal and an addition). However, my web app has no idea what is removed and deleted, as it is just passed an array of tags that I want the post to have.

I can think of 2 ways of handling this:

1. Remove all the associations between tags and the post, and rebuild them.
2. Fetch an array of tags before editing, do a comparison to find out which ones to add an remove.

**What is the best way of handling this situation, and why?**

Comment: I'd go with option (1), because it's less effort in your application and generally not very expensive for the database.  Perform the two operations (`DELETE` then `INSERT`) in a transaction to preserve atomicity.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point about transactions. How about if you've got a one-to-many relationship? Does using up more auto-increment primary keys than necessary matter?

Comment: Why does an association table need an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column?

Comment: With a one-to-many relationship you don't have an association table.

Comment: A one-to-many table doesn't need an auto-incrementing column either.

Comment: When you have a one-to-many relationship between two tables, there is no join table. So the tables are just regular tables, such as `cars`, `owners`. You don't have to use an auto_increment field as their primary key, but its the easiest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was just deleting all the tags associated with that post, and rebuilding them.